# Is it possible to download or search application logs in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am new to cloud foundry and am trying to find out of there is a way for downloading log files or search them in cloud foundry.

I know that I can open the logs files using vmc files  but is there any other way of accessing the logs?

Thanks,
Kinjal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is using the VMC client library, 'cfoundry'.

The following ruby script connects and downloads the three main logs:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'cfoundry'

creds = { :username => ARGV[0], :password => ARGV[1] }
app_name = ARGV[2]

files_to_dl = ['logs/staging.log', 'logs/stderr.log', 'logs/stdout.log']

c = CFoundry::Client.new "http://api.cloudfoundry.com"
c.login creds

app = c.app_by_name app_name

files_to_dl.each do |file|
  begin
    content = app.file(file)

    local_path = file.match(/\/([^\/]+)$/)[1]
    File.open(local_path, 'w') { |f| f.write(content) }

  rescue CFoundry::NotFound
    puts "404!"
  end
end
```

This script assumes you are using the latest version of VMC (older, legacy versions don't use cfoundry) and that you also pass in username, password and application name when calling the script. It will write the contents of the remote files locally.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help Dan. The script worked like a charm and I wouldn't know where to get started as I am not very familiar with ruby script writing

Comment: I have actually since created a CF app that uploads logs from any application to cloud storage at regular intervals, check it out .. https://github.com/danhigham/log_squirrel

Comment: HI,after upgdate vmc to 0.4.7, this script run but the log file is 0 byte