# how to editor cloudfoundry app online?

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, vmc

Sometimes, we only need to change a little line, so vmc push is too slow.

Is there any NodeSJ module or service that can direct edit the code online?

Does Cloudfoundry has a dashboard?

By the way, how do you download `app` and `log` as a zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you look at [how vmc push works](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2011/04/18/what-happens-when-you-vmc-push-an-application-to-cloud-foundry/), you will know from point 11 that the application is packaged by vmc by looking at all the differences and then pushed to the server. So cloudfoundry itself does not have a code editor.
2. To edit your code online you can use another service like http://c9.io and follow these docs to see [how to push to cloudfoundry](https://docs.c9.io/deploying_via_cli.html)
3. > CloudFoundry does not have a dashboard. (as of this writing)

   But there is another service based on micro cloudfoundry, called as [appfog](http://appfog.com/) - and it has all the UI stuff + support for other platforms.
4. Downloading app logs can be done with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13740390/156775)

Comment: 4.had try before, but after upgdate vmc to 0.4.7, this script run but the log file is 0 byte. and how to download app? Is there any gem? I know less about ruby

Comment: @atian25 Here is something that's recently come up. You might want to give it a spin https://github.com/rajaraodv/cfnodelogger  (logs viewer)